# SQL query in MS Acess to search for list of participants who fit certain criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to write a query that generates a list of `participantID`'s that fit certain experiment and participation criteria. **I have these tables:**

- **Participation** that has `participantID`, `participationDate`, and `experimentID`.
- **Experiment** that has `experimentID`, `keyword`.
- **ParticipantRegistry** that has `participantID`, and a bunch of irrelevant fields.

My conditions are:

```
Keyword<>"Robots"
AND ParticipationDate<#12/1/2014#
AND Experiment.ExperimentID=Participation.ExperimentID
```

**Here's the code I wrote which works for finding participants in the Participation table i.e. have participated in an experiment:**

```
SELECT ParticipantID, Keyword
FROM Experiment, ExperimentParticipation
WHERE Experiment.ExperimentID = ExperimentParticipation.ExperimentID 
    AND Keyword<>"Robots" 
    AND ParticipationDate <#12/1/2014#
```

So, the `ParticipantRegistry` table has a whole list of `participantID`'s (even those not included in the participation table i.e. have never participated in experiments).

I want to create a query that has the participants who fit my criteria which I was able to achieve with those who participated in experiments AND those in the `ParticipantRegistry` table who have not participated in any experiments. The problem is participants who have not participated are not in the `Participation` table, so I cannot use the null function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for [left join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894(v=office.12).aspx).

You could completely select your participants from the `ParticipantRegistry` (left join would hold them still, even though some of them are not having *experiments* to be joined with), and join it with the `Participation`. Then at last join it with the `Experiment`.

**UPDATED** :

```
SELECT ParticipantRegistry.ParticipantID, Keyword
FROM (ParticipantRegistry
LEFT JOIN Participation ON (ParticipantRegistry.ParticipantID = Participation.ParticipantID AND ParticipationDate <#12/1/2014#))
LEFT JOIN Experiment ON (Participation.ExperimentID = Experiment.ExperimentID AND Keyword<>"Robots")
```